# iMovie stills turn out blurry in mp4

Tags: imovie

I have high quality pngs and/or pdfs imported into iMovie. They look great on their own. However, when I share to file (using all the highest quality settings), the final result looks blurry. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Please see [ask] for a guide on how to ask a question that a good chance at being answered.  We can't look over your shoulder so tell us what steps you've taken to fix the problem.  Use the search function, at the top right, to see if your question has already been asked & answered.  Adding screenshots of your problem will help, also.

Comment: What version of iMovie? What version of macOS? ~~ Have you tried importing .jpg formatted files? Preview should be able to open .png and .pdf files and Export in .jpg format. Give that try and report back

Comment: Are you considering the potential difference in input & output resolution? No good having an input of 6000x4000 & an output of 1920x1080 if you're trying to display 2 pages of A4 legibly

Comment: thanks all. To elaborate, the images are a time series of detailed maps (rasters) which I am animating. I have a mac 10.12.3; iMovie 10.1.4. I've tried all combinations of pdf, tif, png, and pdf at between 200-800dpi. I am writing them as . mp4 and .mov. All results are blurry, especially text, though I prefer the sharpness/file size ratio of the pngs. Funny enough the animations made with pngs at 200 dpi (1.2mb) aren't that much worse the those made at 800 dpi.

Comment: sorry, meant to say: pdf, tif, png, and jpg

Comment: DPI has absolutely no bearing on image quality or size other that if you print it on paper. You need to be looking at the *actual pixel dimensions*. Screen dpi depends entirely on 'how big the TV is' but could nominally be considered to be 72 for a regular computer monitor. For a standard TV picture [HD] your output is entirely dependant on that. At full resolution, you have an image 1920x1080.

Comment: regardless of dpi or actual pixel dimensions, image resolution becomes blurred. If I use an online converter (i.e. from png stills to an mp4), it looks a lot better - but this gives me little control. I tried to take two of these sharp mp4s from the online converter and combine them sequentially with Quicktime but the final result was blurry again - just as blurry as the original iMovie

Comment: By the way, @Tetsujin changing dpi directly changes actual pixel dimensions. In any case, does anyone out there know how to get a sharper resolution closer to that of the actual pngs used to create the animation? Maybe iMovie just stinks and I need to move to another compiler? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used iMovie in years, so I don't know specifically what it does. However, changing dpi absolutely does not change pixel dimensions, only document 'print' sizes; unless there is some active process trying to match that up to a 'screen size'